# PHP remove entire array from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array like so:

```
[0] => {
       "name": "Sandra",
       "age": 39,
       "pets": true,
       "eyeColor": "hazel"
    }
[1] => {
       "name": "Sandra",
       "age": 23,
       "pets": false,
       "eyeColor": "blue"
    }
[2] => {
       "name": "Sandra",
       "age": 19,
       "pets": true,
       "eyeColor": "hazel"
    }
[3] => {
       "name": "Sandra",
       "age": 27,
       "pets": true,
       "eyeColor": "hazel"
    }
```

Without knowing the `key` as its random, how do I remove an entire array. So I want to remove:

```
{
   "name": "Sandra",
   "age": 19,
   "pets": true,
   "eyeColor": "hazel"
}
```

Where all the values must be exact.

Comment: Walk through the array and look at every element. Compare the element to the one you're looking for. If it is equal, save the current key, and quit the loop. Then, delete the entry using the key you saved.

Comment: something like [this](https://3v4l.org/eKioZ) (untested) might help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to walk through your array and filter out all values that are equal to the one you're looking for.

```
array_filter($yourArray, function ($value) use ($objectYoureLookingFor) {
    if ($value->name     !== $objectYoureLookingFor->name    ) return true;
    if ($value->age      !== $objectYoureLookingFor->age     ) return true;
    if ($value->pets     !== $objectYoureLookingFor->pets    ) return true;
    if ($value->eyeColor !== $objectYoureLookingFor->eyeColor) return true;
    return false;
});
```